# Azure Data Factory - Process SSIS Output

Tags: ssis, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm working to lift an SSIS package into Azure Data Factory V2, and I have successfully set up an IR and executed the package.

Now I'm attempting to work with the results in ADF. This package was originally designed to return a recordset to the calling client. Now that I'm in ADF, I'd like to take the recordset produced by the package and copy it to table storage. However, I see no way to access this recordset from within the ADF pipeline.

Is it possible to access and process this recordset from the host ADF pipeline, or will the package itself have to be modified to no longer return a recordset and perform the copy instead?

Comment: No it's not possible to do this 'natively'. Returning a recordset from an SSIS package to be consumed by something else is _definitely_ a non typical design. I would almost say it's an anti-pattern. How does the client currently consume the recordset? How does SSIS even return a recordset?

Comment: Ha...this is my first foray into ETL development, so I have no answer for you. However, you did confirm my suspicion that this wasn't best practice, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

In the SSIS create a text file as output and copy it to a location/folder in blob or even your on premise folder.

- If you run SSIS on premise,  store it in an on premise folder , use AZCopy 
  tool to move it Azure blob to a BLOB

  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/12/28/step-by-step-using-azcopy-to-transfer-files-to-azure/

  Otherwise, you run SSIS on Azure as you mentioned .Copy the output of
  your rowset to a flat file using flat file connection manager.Create another dataflow task in which you can upload the file  to Azure BLOB in

https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2018/11/20/uploading-azure-blob-ssis/

Now your Azure pipleline can access that BLOB as a source in the copy
   activity and dump it to the table storage as a sink.

Let me know if you need more details on the implementation.